# Getting time discrepancy in Application Insight and Postman

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

Context: During performance evaluation we have noticed that there is a discrepancy in the response time between Postman and Application Insight.

During debugging we found that the response time given obtained from Postman Vs Application Insight are different for the same transaction. We noticed is for different transactions. Why it is so?

Current Configuration: We have application insight for an application which is running within an app service and "**Adaptive Sampling**" is enabled for Application insight.

Note: We are tracing the transaction with tracing ID.

Comparisions Chart:

**Smaller Evaluation:**
[image]

**Medium Evaluation:**

[image]

When the system is under stress the response time goes to min on postman, but in application insight the response time are change drastically.

May be the difference in the response time is lesser but when the number of transactions is more and when we see the 95th (refer the example below) and 99th percentile the game completely changed. Any suggestion on this? Am I missing something?

For example:

**Postman Result:**
[image]

**Application Insight:**

[image]

Comment: AI doesn't take into account the actual latency of sending the request to the api and getting the response back. It can only measure the time it takes the api to create a response.

Comment: As @PeterBons mentioned, the time you'd see in App Insight is the total execution time on the azure side, it does not include the time taken for the response to reach over the network to a client side app like Postman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the suggestion provided by [Peter-Bons](https://stackoverflow.com/users/932728/peter-bons)as an answer so that it will be helpful for other community members.

From the below screenshot application insights won't take the actual latency of sending the request to the api and getting the response back.  The time which we will be seeing in app insights is total execution time on the azure side

[image]